# Can I generate a payment URL with Stripe Checkout?

Tags: forms, url, stripe-payments

I'd like to create a URL that I can share in my newsletter that sends people directly to a Stripe Checkout form to make a small (fixed amount) payment.

With the [new Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client) I can generate the HTML Code to build a button that I can include in a website. I'd like to avoid sending people to a website where they have to click that button, but send them straight to the payment form based on the parameters in a URL. Is this possible?

Comment: Totally agree with you! I've been looking for the exact same solution to simply send a payment URL using Stripe, trying to avoid using other BE providers.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** This is now possible with the launch of Payment Links! Check it out here: [Stripe Payment Links](https://stripe.com/payments/payment-links)

This is unfortunately not possible. `Stripe.js` generates a unique redirect page for each `redirectToCheckout` call using your publishable key. This ensures that the page is unique to each customer so it can be tracked easier.

You can't really get around sending your customers to a website as even legacy Checkout requires the use of JavaScript to generate the payment form.

Comment: this might help: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/starting I had to generate a sessionId then load an html page to call the JS to redirect

Answer (score 4):

You can make an Invoice on stripe.com which will generate an e-mail with link to the payment. Using that, you don't need any webserver.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

This can be done with a custom script on your end. As mentioned earlier each page has a unique ID used for tracking, therefore it cant be reused.

But with something like a simple PHP script which initiates this payment you can surely use the URL to the php script as a "constant" url to the payment.

The php would and JS would look something like this after having imported the stripe PHP SDK using composer and stripe.js

```
<?php
$stripecheckout = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'success_url' => 'https://success.url',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://cancel.url',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'amount' => 100,
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'name' => '1 item',
      'description' => 'This is my item description',
      'quantity' => 1,
    ],
  ]
]);
 ?>
```

and then this javascript

```
 <script>
 var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
 stripe.redirectToCheckout({
 sessionId: '<?php echo $stripecheckout->id; ?>'
 }).then(function (result) {
   // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
   // error, display the localized error message to your customer
   // using `result.error.message`.
 });
 </script>
```

This will require some customization and error handling from your end, but in my opinion would be the best solution

Comment: I'd vote for this to be the accepted answer. It works.

Comment: it isn't actually answer to question. Its just traditional way to implement new payment service.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not available through Stripe directly. I've found two options for this:

1. [Payfunnels](https://start.payfunnels.com/signup). The only downside is that it's not free (only 14 days free trial). Connects with your Stripe BE and super easy to issue a payment Link & Invoice.
2. [Wave](https://www.waveapps.com/) accounting it totally free & connects with Stripe, the downside is that it's not as quick as option 1. You can create an invoice in there, email it to your customer directly, or send it to yourself via email (remember to tick the PDF option), in that email there will be a payment link which you can send via your chosen means of communication.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now it's possible. Stripe introduce share a payment link API. But problem is API is still beta. But you can use beta API you have to join beta.

follow this instruction to join beta. click ***reach out to us*** button [click here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#:%7E:text=Creating%20Payment%20Links%20via%20API%20is%20in%20beta.%20If%20you%E2%80%99d%20like%20to%20try%20it%20out%20and%20provide%20feedback%2C%20please). Then you can see below APIs.[[stripe share link APIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqtfH.png)]